# Selenium Manager - Artifactory Binaries

Tags: artifactory, seleniummanager

I am currently trying to get Selenium Manager to point to Artifactory to fetch our ChromeDrivers.

I am wondering if anyone has successfully done this and how you did it? I know we need to set the env variable, however my question is more around what did you point Selenium-Manager to for artifactory?

Thanks

Tried pointing to the package directly, tried various urls.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your own code trials? We need to see a [repro] before we can provide an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.